# Excessive Memory Consumption in MS SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I currently have a project which requires me to analyze a big data of a company. I have at least 40 million rows of customers which is stored in MS SQL 2008 database. The problem is whenever I try to query the table, it takes a long time to finish and takes excessive memory consumption as well, which in effect may shutdown the system due to the insufficient memory. Any idea to solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: Table structure would help us understand more.

Comment: ... and the query you execute as well, with the corresponding query plan.

Comment: Is this amazon or something with 4E7 Customers?